# Minimum path cover in DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, bipartite

I want to know if there exists an efficient algorithm for computing the minimum path-cover in a Directed Acyclic Graph. Please don't confuse the minimum "path-cover" with "vertex-disjoint path-cover". For the latter, I know an efficient algorithm using Maximum matching of the corresponding Bipartite graph. But that applies only for the vertex-disjoint case. Can the same algorithm be relaxed to obtain the answer for the path cover when each vertex can be visited multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the same algorithm could be relaxed as you wish. Just compute transitive closure of the original graph.

You can find an explanation of the complete algorithm in Wikipedia article "Dilworth's theorem", in section ["Proof via König's theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem#Proof_via_K.C3.B6nig.27s_theorem).

Comment: I may be wrong but wouldn't the transitive closure run in O(N^3) ? Would this be the time complexity of your algorithm? Because I was searching for an O(N*M) algorithm just like the disjoint case.

Comment: @divanshu: I don't know if O(N*M) algorithm exists for this case. As for time complexity of this algorithm, you can get transitive closure in O(N*M) as explained [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/efficient-algorithm-for-retrieving-the-transitive-closure-of-a-directed-acyclic). But after this you'll compute bipartite matching for dense graph; the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm with complexity O(V^2.5) is the best practical algorithm I know; which gives overall complexity O(V^2.5). Or you could use approach based on fast matrix multiplication with O(V^2.376) complexity.